# Android local service binding and background thread

Tags: android

My app has a local service that I want to be running all the time, which I accomplish by having the service start another thread, and respond to requests send to its `Handler`.
Binding to the service returns the background thread's Handler, so that client activities can issue requests.

So far so good.

My app uses `Fragment`s which need to use the service, in order to set their initial state. When the fragments are instantiated in response to user input, that's OK, because by that time the service is bound to the fragment's parent activity. That is to say, `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected` has been called by the framework, and the activity knows about a `Handler` that its Fragments can use to communicate with the service.

My problems start when my activity is re-instantiated in response to an orientation change. It appears, from my reading of the stack trace, that in this situation the framework recreates all the activity fragments in the same pass through the main thread's message loop, *before* `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected` has been called, so they cannot access the service in the recreation phase.

The only solution that I have found is for the service to publish the Handler associated with its background thread to application-global state. (I am subclassing `Application` for that purpose, though there are other techniques.) I am after all using its 'threadness' rather than its 'serviceness'.

This seems to be a simple and effective way to do something that Android seems to want to make awkward and complicated. Apart from the usual general reservations about global state, are there any Android-specific considerations my approach overlooks? Or any better ways to achieve the same objective, which I hope is clear?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you may be interested in looking into [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). IntentService is a Service that starts its own Thread upon binding and it handles Intents as they are received. Have you looked into it already?

Comment: Thanks. That has put me on a good track. I don't want to use `IntentService` because my background thread has specific initialization that I don't want to reincur, but `startService(Intent)` is probably what I need. I'd not given enough consideration to this.

Comment: Actually I don't think this will work, since I need to pass arbitrary objects by reference to the background thread's handler, and I don't think I can pass these via the Intent mechanism. I need to put them in a Message that I send to a Handler.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but can't you make those objects you are trying to pass implement the Parcelable interface?. This will allow you to marshall/unmarshall these objects and pass them to the newly created Thread on IntentService. Take a look at this link on how to do this. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/03/example-to-implement-parcelable.html

Comment: Thanks but making my objects Parcelable will be overkill for what I'm doing. Pass by reference is what I required.

Answer (score 1):

Android has its way of doing things - which is often awkward, but - to be fair - only because it is meant to solve some really awkward problems.

You can:

- either go all the way using Android's architecture,
- or try to avoid it (with the usual exception of UI).

Combining the two approaches is tricky, because it often leaves you with the worst of both worlds.

In your case (I understand that you are using bound services because you need to pass real references - so switching to intent-based services is - for some reason - impossible), I would remove both the Service and the Application subclass. In the scenario you are describing you don't need any of them at all. A simple, pure Java singleton will do.

The other combination is to embrace the Android way. In such case you would create a wrapper around the code that connects to the `Service` and make it subclass a `Loader`. This way you could have a single instance of connection managed by `LoaderManager`.

Probably the original authors of the API would want you to rework your application so that all data is read from a content provider and modified by an asynchronous service (or maybe not, who knows...).

Comment: Thanks. My original reason for using a service, as far as I can remember, is that I have to do work in response to an alarm fielded by a BroadcastReceiver, and I wasn't sure that there was going to be anything protecting my thread from dying if it's not started from a service. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Threads are not in any way associated with services (how would that even work?!) so it does not matter if they are created inside a service or anywhere else. If you need your process to stay alive (sort of getting your foot in the door) you can as well create a completely empty class extending Service and call Context#startService. It will be considered "running" (whatever that means...) until you call Context#stopService. You don't have to touch it in any way or put any of your code inside.

Comment: The question of how a thread might be associated with a service did occur to me, but if it's not then starting one looks like an easy way to defeat Android's attempts to manage application components in the context of resource depletion.To manage the single instance of my background thread it seems simplest to call startService off the alarm BroadcastReceiver, and have the service's onCreate start the thread.